# Inheritance value from the exposed filter

Tags: views, 7

I've got content-type with two double-valued fields field_price1 and field_price2. There are interior names. I've also got page view (its machine name is search) displaying contents. I've got search with some filters. I decided to create one exposed filter connected with field_price1 field with between operator. Second filter isn't exposed and it is connected with field_price2 field.

I want to display content in the view only if its field_price1 or field_price2 is between values given by user in the search. So that, filter for field_price2 field has to inherit the value from the first exposed filter. I created custom module named customSearch with code posted below in customSearch.module file.

```
function customSearch_views_pre_view(&$view) {  
  if ($view->name == 'search') {        
    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');   
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['min'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['min'];
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['max'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['max'];
    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
  }
}
```

Unforntunately, I've got errors.

> Notice: Undefined property: view::$exposed_input in
>   customSearch_views_pre_view() in line
>   `$filters['field_price2_value']['value']['min'] =
>   $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['min'];`
>
> Notice: Undefined property: view::$exposed_input in
>   customSearch_views_pre_view() in line
>   `$filters['field_price2_value']['value']['max'] =
>   $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['max'];

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Did you expose the first filter?

Comment: Yeah. In search I've got two additional inputs.

Comment: What happens if you put 0 and 100 in the min and max exposed filter?

Comment: These are the same errors.

Comment: I don't know why I should code $filters['field_price2_value'] insted $filters['field_price2'] and why I code ['min'] and ['max'] - I never name such fields

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
function customSearch_views_pre_view(&$view) {  
  if ($view->name == 'search') {        
    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');   
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['min'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['min'];
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['max'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['max'];
    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
  }
}
```

with

```
function customSearch_views_pre_execute(&$view) {  
  if ($view->name == 'search') {        
    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');   
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['min'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['min'];
    $filters['field_price2_value']['value']['max'] = $view->exposed_input['field_price1_value']['max'];
    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
  }
}
```

And then clear your cache.

Comment: Ok, There are no errors, yet it doesn't work properly. It works for field_price1, but it doesn't work for field_price2. I fill inputs with appropriate values for field_price2 and in the result I don't receive any contents.

Comment: Did you setup the OR groups?

Comment: Yes, I've got two groups. In first I've got previous filters and operator AND. In second group I've got two filters we write about  and opreator OR. I've got AND operator between groups.

Comment: Try having just two groups. First group field_price1 and in the next group field_price2 and between the groups use OR.

Comment: But what should I do with previous filters?

Comment: I have 5 previous field (title, category, etc.) and two new we write about. If user fill a few filters I'd like to display more detailed result.So that, I decided to choose AND operator between filters.

Comment: I remained just two groups. First group field_price1 and in the next group field_price2 and between the groups OR operator. I removed the other filters. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for filter connected with field_price2.